# Putting part of scraping process in loop

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I am making a little scraping project for myself but I need some help. Here is the code and I will try to explain as best as I can in what part I need help.

This is my code that does everything manually :/ The part I need help is in def test_untitled_test_case(self): #you can see it In code, that's where everything I need happens and that's the part I would like to loop.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoAlertPresentException
import unittest, time, re

class UntitledTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(30)
        self.base_url = "https://www.google.com/"
        self.verificationErrors = []
        self.accept_next_alert = True

    def test_untitled_test_case(self):
        driver = self.driver
        driver.get("http://portal.ujn.gov.rs/RezultatiPretrage.aspx?tab=1&pocetna=1&tp=F1KlmN+JuNI=&nad=HYaKK73A0XelYBXaLv+GK5iiW756vgDY")
        driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_cphMain_gvJavneNabavke_ctl02_btnPregled").click()
        driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_cphMain_grvChild_ctl03_btnPregled").click()
        driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_cphMain_btnNazad").click()
        driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_cphMain_btnNazad").click()
        driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_cphMain_gvJavneNabavke_ctl03_btnPregled").click()
        driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_cphMain_grvChild_ctl02_btnPregled").click()
        driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_cphMain_btnNazad").click()
        driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_cphMain_btnNazad").click()
        driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_cphMain_gvJavneNabavke_ctl04_btnPregled").click()
        driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_cphMain_grvChild_ctl02_btnPregled").click()
        driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_cphMain_btnNazad").click()
        driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_cphMain_btnNazad").click()

    def is_element_present(self, how, what):
        try: self.driver.find_element(by=how, value=what)
        except NoSuchElementException as e: return False
        return True

    def is_alert_present(self):
        try: self.driver.switch_to_alert()
        except NoAlertPresentException as e: return False
        return True

    def close_alert_and_get_its_text(self):
        try:
            alert = self.driver.switch_to_alert()
            alert_text = alert.text
            if self.accept_next_alert:
                alert.accept()
            else:
                alert.dismiss()
            return alert_text
        finally: self.accept_next_alert = True

    def tearDown(self):
        self.driver.quit()
        self.assertEqual([], self.verificationErrors)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

The  driver.get("http://portal.ujn.gov.rs/RezultatiPretrage.aspx?tab=1&pocetna=1&tp=F1KlmN+JuNI=&nad=HYaKK73A0XelYBXaLv+GK5iiW756vgDY") is search result for word периодични, and then it lists all these tenders. When you click the little magnifying glass It enters into details for that specific tender.

And the details that I need are found in  Обавештење о закљученом уговору. From there I need to scrape Процењена вредност and  Уговорена вредност.

The steps would be, from the main url, enter into each tender by clicking on magnifying glass, clicking on Обавештење о закљученом уговору(if there is one, if there isn't get back to the main url, if there is clicking on it and scraping needed data), and getting back to the main url. And looping that whole
 process.
Aaand that would be all I need. Hope I explained it well enough.

Any tips/guidance would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, can you clarify what the issue is?

Comment: Well there are tens of thousands of tenders, and I would like to automate the process of going into each one and scraping the data. The part that I don't know how to do is how to make loop for the process of going into one, checking if there is info I need, if there is, scrape it, if there isn't go back to main url and go to the next one.

Answer (score 0):

Try to pass all links into a list. Safe all your links beforehand in a txt ,JSON or [XML](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) -File. Than parse over them and safe them into a list, i skipped that step because i couldnt import your libraries, so nvm. But afterwards its quite easy, just call a `for-loop` in which you select in each iteration one link of your list, and execute the command you wanted.

```
class UntitledTestCase(unittest.TestCase):

def __init__(self,list_of_weblinks):
  self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
  self.driver.implicitly_wait(30)
  self.base_url = "https://www.google.com/"
  self.verificationErrors = []
  self.accept_next_alert = True
  self.list_of_weblinks=list_of_weblinks

def test_untitled_test_case(self):
  driver = self.driver

  for element in self.list_of_weblinks:
    driver.get(element).click()

def is_element_present(self, how, what):
    try: self.driver.find_element(by=how, value=what)
    except NoSuchElementException as e: return False
    return True

def is_alert_present(self):
    try: self.driver.switch_to_alert()
    except NoAlertPresentException as e: return False
    return True

def close_alert_and_get_its_text(self):
    try:
        alert = self.driver.switch_to_alert()
        alert_text = alert.text
        if self.accept_next_alert:
            alert.accept()
        else:
            alert.dismiss()
        return alert_text
    finally: self.accept_next_alert = True

def tearDown(self):
    self.driver.quit()
    self.assertEqual([], self.verificationErrors)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()


test=UntitledTestCase(list_of_weblinks)
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. There are too many tenders/links. I don't know how to list them all.

Comment: I was told I could use API on another forum

http://portal.ujn.gov.rs/Dokumenti/ObavestenjeOZakljucenomUgovoru.aspx?idd=2689025&idp=2310944&vz=2  

This is the URL: http://portal.ujn.gov.rs/Dokumenti/ObavestenjeOZakljucenomUgovoru.aspx

These are the parameters that are passed to the backend which then scans the database and finds the document: idd = 2689025 & idp = 2310944 & vz = 2

Now for each search you should have iddd = somenumber & idp = somenumber & vz = 2

But I don't have slightest idea how to use API for scraping purposes or how to get all those ID-s.

Comment: Sorry mate, but i never used the API you are using, thats as far i can help you. But in general you should try to collect all the links in one place, and afterwards loop over them. Where do you get those links from ?

Comment: Thank you anyway. Do you know how can I collect all links maybe ? The way to get them manually  would be to enter into every single tender and copy the link, but there are too many tenders to do that. There is like 10,000 tenders, maybe 20, 50 :)

Comment: where do you grab those tenders ? from a website or out of a file ? I feel you haha :D

Comment: I know :)) well, http://portal.ujn.gov.rs/RezultatiPretrage.aspx?tab=1&pocetna=1&tp=F1KlmN+JuNI=&nad=HYaKK73A0XelYBXaLv+GK5iiW756vgDY this is the main url containing all the tenders, and when you click magnifying glass you enter individual tender and that's the link

Comment: Paul, I managed to find list off all urls that I need. How should I implement that list in my code :)

Comment: Nice, thats a good start. Yesterday i visited your webpages but just thougth about random html-requests or searching for hyperlinks with the help of plugins maybe. Do you have the list as a txt or which format ?

Comment: I have it in excel, but I can make it text or csv or whatever would be best. Now the list of links I have point to every individual tender, BUT there is still a part where I need to go into Обавештење о закљученом уговору where the data I need is. Is it possible to make loop do, click on the link from list, when there, click on Обавештење о закљученом уговору, scrape data, and go to the next link. Thnx for your time